# Good Heuristic for Connect-K AI

Tags: python, performance, artificial-intelligence, heuristics

I'm writing a Connect-K simple AI (no pruning, 4-ply only). I was wondering what is the **best heuristic** that is fast to calculate.

Something better than what I have:

```
def eval(board, player)
    connections = 0
    magnitude = 0
    for x in range(0, self.boardW(board)):
        for y in range(0, self.boardH(board)):
            if(self.get_player(board, x, y) == player): #assuming x and y are in bounds
                temp = 1
                # keep checking in this direction to find the max temp can be
                if (magnitude < temp):
                    magnitude = temp
            if(self.get_player(board, x, y) == player):
                connection += 1
        ........
    return connection**2 + magnitude**2
```

Basically this is supposed to return the maximum connections any spot on the board has with its adjacent spots, plus how many consecutive items are in any of the 8 directions (*up, down, left, right, top-left, down-left, ...*)

My **k** will be larger than 4; thus I can't do an exhaustive tree search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [min-max](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax) search could be useful in this scenario, possibly combined with a simplified [MCTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_tree_search). Basically, a deeper recursion would let you reach more end states of the game. By analyzing which player wins in each of these cases, you get a better understanding of the value of a certain move.

The min-max method is quite useful for games between two players, and is widely used for board games such as this. MCTS might be a bit overkill, but the general idea there is to trade an extensive search for a random, deeper search. For example, instead of having a branching factor of 20, and only 5 levels of recursion (20^5 = 3.2 million), you could randomly choose 10 of the branches and have 6-7 recursion steps with the same amount of calculation.

Something that has yielded good results in a similar project (an AI for checkers) was to decrease the branching factor further down in the recursion. By defining the max branching (the maximum number of branches to be explored in a recursion step), let this number be larger than the typical branching for the top level, and decrease further down the recursion to a much smaller number (5-10 quite soon, and 1-3 at the bottom). This way, you get the best of both worlds. You explore all imminent moves, but you also get a lot of information about how they affect the later parts of the game.

A quick recap: Using MCTS and min-max, you can find a lot of end-states. If the opponent won, give it a large negative score. If you won, give it a large positive score If neither, you can give it a 0, or use the function you showed in your question. Let the score of a parent game state depend on the scores of their children by utilizing the min-max algorithm.